# "passwd" can not read password from standard input on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, users, passwd

[image]i'm trying to make a small shell script that creates a new account, it needs to not show the password when writing it. But i got a error and can't find a solution.[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: By the way, as a general rule, reading input from the command line at run time like this is a very bad idea: it makes the script impossible (very hard) to automate, it is very easy to make a typo, and it is hard for the user. It is better to pass the username as an argument and then only read the password from the commandline so it isn't shown anywhere: like `./bash.sh $username`. Finally, why are you doing this instead of using `adduser` or, if you don't have that, `useradd`?

Comment: Sorry i will post it as a text next time, i didn't use adduser because i followed a youtube video, i am very new to all of this so i don't really know what i am doing

Comment: Please, add text as text, not as images.  You were already told once to do this, but you keep adding further screenshots of text.

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't know how to copy and paste from my virtual machine. It doesn't work the normal way.

Comment: "_i am very new to all of this so i don't really know what i am doing_" - then please don't use Kali. It's a specialist distribution for professionals who are familiar with Linux-based platforms

Comment: @roaima It's part of my learning cours, i don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to create a bash script that will take username & password as input, create user & set its password, try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "please enter username: "
read username
echo -n "please enter password for $username: "
read -s password
echo

useradd $USERNAME
printf '%s\n' "$password" | passwd --stdin "$username"
```

The `-s` option is used with the read to hide the input typed by the user on the terminal.

Comment: Hi, the script runs but when it asks to write a password it doesnt let me write anything.

Comment: @NezukoTM it must hidden, write your password and press enter to check if the user is properly created, if it's successful then in the last it will show:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully. or you can post a pic

Comment: I dont know how to send pics here but it says
Pleaser enter password for test:
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /ect/psswd; try again later.
passwd: unrecognized option ,--stdin
usage: psswd (options) (login)

Comment: @NezukoTM you can edit your question to provide further details, if that's the case you must use the script with root user or with the user who have sudoers rights by using "sudo" before the script e.g. sudo ./myscript.sh

Comment: Note that the implementation of `passwd` that this user is using is not accepting the `--stdin` option.

Comment: @csx4 I added the image

Comment: @NezukoTM yes rights issue, use sudo before the script name as stated above or use with root user

Comment: @csx4 How do i switch to the root user again ? I forgot

Comment: @NezukoTM if you know root user's password use "su -" or if you have sudoers rights use: "sudo -i" it may ask your current user password

Comment: @csx4 It says that i cannot find the file with root user

Comment: @NezukoTM exit out of there, better to use sudo before the script name it will run

Comment: @csx4 It looks like it works with sudo but i'm not sure, when i tried it with the username test it says that test already exists. But when i try again with a new username(in that case test1) it tells me the same error as earlier